# Sql Server Date Query not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query, shown below. However when I run this query I get rows whose [date_effective] is prior to 14th Feb 2014.  Why? I have dates of 1/1/1980 showing up.

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM D_CORPACTIONS_MSCI
   WHERE [date_effective] >= '14 February 2014' 
     AND [ca_status] = 'EXPECTED' 
      OR [ca_status] = 'CONFIRMED' 
      OR [ca_status] = 'UNDETERMINED'
ORDER BY [date_effective]
```

Comment: Basically, what you're asking is - give my rows, that
- have `date_effective` >= 14Feb2014 and `ca_status` is `'EXPECTED'`
and rows, that
- have `ca_status` `'CONFIRMED'` or `'UNDETERMINED'`, **no matter what `date_effective` does it have**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `and` and `or` are conflicting each other.

Therefore the matched rows aren't correct.

Try to encapsulate the `or` statements or, it this case, use an `in`:

```
select *
from   d_corpactions_msci
where  date_effective >= '14 february 2014'
and    ca_status in ('EXPECTED', 'CONFIRMED', 'UNDETERMINED')
order
by     date_effective
```

Also, don't rely on the date format on client or server by converting the date:

```
where  date_effective >= convert(datetime, '20140214', 112)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   d_corpactions_msci 
WHERE  ( date_effective >= '14 February 2014' ) 
       AND ( ca_status = 'EXPECTED' 
              OR ca_status = 'CONFIRMED' 
              OR ca_status = 'UNDETERMINED' ) 
ORDER  BY date_effective
```

Answer (score 0):

Patrick Hofman and Kashif - they have already answered your question.

You can also use UNION ALL

```
SELECT * 
    FROM D_CORPACTIONS_MSCI
    WHERE ([date_effective] >= '14 February 2014') 
    AND [ca_status] = 'EXPECTED' 
UNION ALL
    SELECT * 
    FROM D_CORPACTIONS_MSCI
    WHERE ([date_effective] >= '14 February 2014') 
    AND [ca_status] = 'CONFIRMED' 
UNION ALL
    SELECT * 
    FROM D_CORPACTIONS_MSCI
    WHERE ([date_effective] >= '14 February 2014') 
    AND [ca_status] = 'UNDETERMINED')
ORDER BY [date_effective]
```

The `UNION ALL` performs better than `OR`.

Comparing – “OR” vs. “UNION ALL” My understanding as per below:

1. The “OR” version query has two operators (steam aggregation and merge join) whereas “UNION ALL” version has concatenation operator only.
2. Cardinality estimate is inaccurate for “OR” version query.
3. The sub-tree cost for “UNION ALL” query is way less than the “OR” version.

Comment: Why all the overhead?

Comment: Hi Patrick, I thought UNION ALL performs better than OR 
Comparing – “OR” vs. “UNION ALL”
 
My understanding as per below: 

1.       The “OR” version query has two operators (steam aggregation and merge join) whereas “UNION ALL” version has concatenation operator only.
 
2.       Cardinality estimate is inaccurate for “OR” version query.
 
3.       The sub-tree cost for “UNION ALL” query is way less than the “OR” version.

Comment: Source: Source: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:qBH7HSQJLa0J:sqltouch.blogspot.com/2013/03/or-vs-union-all-have-you-thought-about.html+&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk

Comment: That's why you should use an `in` for this.